# Entity framework inheritance strategies - one model, multiple EDMX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have three databases, in each of them inheritance is implemented in different way for the same conceptual model. For example, model looks like this:

[image: This is the result that i would like to get.] 
[image: My model.]

I have my entities in separated project, i moved my Model.tt and changed a line to

```
const string inputFile = @"..\DAL\Test1Model.edmx";
```

My DAL contains three EDMX - one for each inheretance type.

First question is:

1. How to manage that all EDMX generates (use) only one mutually model - the one in separate project? Mutually entitiy model which i could use on Client?

As for inheritance and Entity Framework, i know that there is a "problem" with Table per concrete type inheritance. The thing is that Base class should be abstract - generated entities of TPC would be different from other two inheritance strategies (TPT and TPH).

Second question:

2. Is there a workaround for this? In this case, entities are not the same and number 1 cannot be done.

I have generic DAL, and i want to switch between databases and different inheritance mapping.
I am using Entity Framework 5.

Comment: I'm not putting as a answer because its just a strategy but change the TT files to create interfaces to all the models and create a different connection on the web config to all the DB then create the context based on the config name returning the interface.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid : I'm not sure what do you mean exactly. So you say that 3 EDMX will have 3 TT files? Can i have 3 EDMX and 1 TT file - model is the same?

Comment: you have to alter your tt to implement one interface `public partial class MyEntitiContext : IMyEntitiContext{}` and all tables to `IDbSet<IEntityObject>` and basicaly use 3 different Contexts/EDMX defined by name and only instantiate the one you want to use passing it to the interface. Yes you can just include the TT file as a Link so it appears as 3 files but only exist once as a file.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid I already tried something similar, but maybe i was wrong. I will try again and post result.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid I managed to switch database by creating factory wich returns my entities instance. I though that in newer versions of EF there is a ,,generic trick'' for one model, multiple mappings (so that i don't have to have n .tt model files and set same namespace). By the way, problem no 2. is actual. I think that i am going to use MEF for this.Tnx Pedro.